# is it possible to make my pc as server and my android as client via bluetooth?

Tags: android, database, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'd like to know is it possible to make my pc and android communicate via Bluetooth as client and server? i want to make my android send data to database in my PC. if it's possible, can you recommend me what kind of database that can be used? thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. But no, we can't, because Stack Overflow is not for recommendations, as you can see by reading the [help]. But the answer really is "whatever database you want", so it doesn't help much. Look around, do some searches and when you have a *specific* question about a problem, feel free to write a question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Databases should typically be accessed by HTTP. Much easier, and less battery drain on the Android device

Comment: i'm sorry, i guess my question is not specific enough.Actually, the reason why i choose Bluetooth because i don't want to depend on any provider. in my project i'll use Bluetooth low energy (BLE), which has range around 60 m and can form server and client connection. the things that make me confuse are how to set bluetooth in my pc as client? and how to connect it to my database? do i need external bluetooth? or should i use bluecove to interface my pc's bluetooth to java?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible but not easy and pointless, why do you need to access a database if the Bluetooth range is about 10m? its easier to access directly the PC instead

What you need to do is create a webserver and access your database via Internet Protocols this will remove the range restriction and its easier to implement. There are a lot of solutions like apache, IIS or Tomcat, and you'll have to learn another language to speak with your application like Java, PHP, or Angular, but its the modern way to do this kind of things...

Comment: i'm sorry, i guess my question is not specific enough.Actually, the reason why i choose Bluetooth because i don't want to depend on any provider. in my project i'll use Bluetooth low energy (BLE), which has range around 60 m and can form server and client connection. the things that make me confuse are how to make bluetooth in my pc as client? and how to connect it to my database? do i need external bluetooth or should i use bluecove to interface my pc's bluetooth to java?